# How to add soap basic auth request to WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, basic-authentication, soapheader

How can I had soap AUTH BASIC auth to a WSDL, so who ever reads the WSDL knows I require that operation for a specific method ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the example bellow I have managed to pass the SOAP basic autentication to the php webservice on the other end.
The PHP.net/Soapclient has a simple working example, but in csharp I found this link to be a solution to my problem.

[link](http://www.intellitechture.com/Calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/)

Michaelis.MockService is the Webservice library extracted you may see an example on how to do this in:
[link](http://www.mono-project.com/Web_Services) Mono project website.

```
Michaelis.MockService service = new Michaelis.MockService();

// Create the network credentials and assign
// them to the service credentials
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential(“Inigo.Montoya”, “Ykmfptd”);
Uri uri = new Uri(service.Url);
ICredentials credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, “Basic”);
service.Credentials = credentials;

// Be sure to set PreAuthenticate to true or else
// authentication will not be sent.
service.PreAuthenticate = true;

// Make the web service call.
service.Method();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify this, as far as I know.

Comment: I have not found what I was really intending but found a solution. 

Using csharp client since in php the example on the website of soapclient is simple.

[link](http://www.intellitechture.com/Calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/)

Comment: @netcrash: then please post your solution as an answer, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Done should have submited has an answer did not realise that sorry.